# What's the function of google_service.json in the GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I create two android app to test GCM, after testing them I find the GCM server identify the app through the registered token(get from `InstanceID.getToken(senderId, scope, bundle))`, the project information(I modified `project_number`, `client_id` and `package_name`) in the `google_service.json` does not impact the device receive the push message. 
The [guidance](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) also tell us Copy the `google-services.json` file you just downloaded into the `app/` or `mobile/` directory of your Android Studio project. But when I put it in the library root directory, the gcm demos also work well. 
So what is the function of this file, what on earth does it work in gcm?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client,

> The Google Services plugin for Gradle parses configuration information from the google-services.json file. Add the plugin to your project by updating your top-level build.gradle and your app-level build.gradle files as follows:
>
> Add the dependency to your project's top-level build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

> Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It populates the `R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId` value which you use in the following two lines of code to get the token.

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

Comment: is this the only function the .json file gives us? because I can insert the SENDER_ID myself in a string. So when I do that, is the .json file still be nessary?

Comment: @DennisAnderson it is necessary for almost all google services libraries to work and compile, so get used to use .json if u r planing to get the new google services updates